# Weird behavior of vulkan Image layout transition for swapchain image while using a seperate command buffer

Tags: graphics, rendering, vulkan

I can not past code snapshot here, because of too many codes. I will describe my problem by Vulkan validation error and renderdoc.

### What I do

I create a render pass, initial/final layouts of the render target attachment(swapchain image) both are `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL`   . So I need to make some image layout transitions.

- **While creating swapchain**: transite the layouts of swapchain images from `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED` to `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL`.
- **At begining of a frame**: transit the current layout of current render target to `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL`.
- **Before submiting rendering command buffer** prior to the call of `vkQueuePresentKHR`: transite the current layout of current render target to `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR`.

Also, I create two seperate command buffer, one for recording rendering command which will be submitted before `vkQueuePresentKHR`, another for recording `vkCmdPipelineBarrier` to transite the image layout which will be submitted before submitting render command buffer.

### Validation Error

First validation error pops up after submitting rendering command buffer, second validation error pops up after the call `vkQueuePresentKHR`.
[image]

It is weird that the first validation error is in submitting rendering command buffer instead of the command buffer for transiting image layout.

### The first frame recorded by Renderdoc

The first frame is presenting **swapchain image 157** as showed in renderdoc recording.

- The image layout transition while creating swapchain
  [image]
- The image layout transition before submiting rendering command buffer
  [image]

My two command buffers are allocated from same command pool. Does anyone know what's happening here?

**Upadate:**

if I use rendering command buffer to record `vkCmdPipelineBarrier`, no validation error appears. But I don know why a seperate trainsition command buffer can not work normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be your synchronization problem, the layout transition maybe not finished before you executing the present or submit command.

However, there is not need to do transition manually, just set src/dst imagelayout of attachment description to be UNDEFINED/PRESENT_SRC, everything will be fine.

Comment: Do you mean UNDEFINED  can be compatible with any src layout? Also, I do think it's caused by the unfinished layout transition. According to https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/vkCmdPipelineBarrier.html , the vkCmdPipelineBarrier is set up a barrier in a queue, which means the commands after the barrier wiil be executed after finishing the execution of the commands before the barrier

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: @wangsy ,yes, you can set srclayout in attachmentdescription to be undefined.  Do you noticed the synchronization scoped defined by the stagemask, src/dst StageMask defines what should happen before/after barrier. Do you set them properly?

Comment: UNDEFINED  initial layout of attachmentdescription is not compitable with load op. I can not use this

Comment: @wangsy then you should change the imagelayout first, try to set the dststage to be COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT or simply ALL_COMMAND(do not recommend)

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by the incorrect usage of separate command buffer. I submit the command buffer recording barrier before rendering command buffer. I think the execution barrier is ensuring the command execution sequence consistent with the recording sequence relative to barrier commands. My way will have the following execution results

vkCmdPipelineBarrier

vkCmdBeginRenderpass

vkCmdBindVertexBuffer

vkCmdDraw

vkCmdEndRenderpass

I set up barrier for transiting the layout of the image genreated by renderpass to VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR. However, my wrong practice results in executing transition before executing a render pass. I’m so stupid.